# Unity3d, Kinect + Zigfu

Tags: unity-game-engine, kinect

i have zigfu running in Unity3d on my Mac OS10.7/all the examples in the ZDK work nicely EXCEPT when i try to substitute the enclosed models-- i tried many other models (my own/blender imports, other mixamo, mixamo-unity fbx.exports, etc-all load beautifully in the encloed scenes, i target all the  skeleton bones on the zigfu script, set user(s) + model target depending on the zigfu example on the correct scripts,  and still nothing works. no error messages.can't figure this out! any ideas? tips, suggestions, experience with this? thanks.

Comment: Can you send me a Unity3d project that isn't working? Or one of the other models you are trying? It's hard to debug without seeing exactly how you setup your scene

Comment: so generous/how do i mail files to you?

Comment: can you post any code examples of what you've tried?

Comment: yhanks for help-turns out i was targeting the wrong instancein my script!